# Upgrade existing database after making table changes to Entity Framework edmx file

Tags: sql, entity-framework

I inherited an old c# project that used Entity Framework 4 to create the database.  I need to add two new fields into a table, so I opened SQL Management Studio and added the new fields then ran a "Update model from database" in Visual Studio.  It added my new fields.

The problem is many people have this c# program installed on their desktops with the older database (SQL Express installed on each machine locally).  If I just send them an installer with this new schema, will it update their database automatically or do I need to call something in my code to update their database.

The code right now does

```
if (context.DatabaseExists())
{
    //database exists, load what we need
}
else
{
    context.CreateDatabase();
}
```

Do I need to call a context update or something if the databases don't match?  Also I am worried about losing their data, I need the users existing data to still be there.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is [migrations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli).

Comment: This might help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/ee358769(v=vs.100)